# Adding ArrayLists to another ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I want to find the minimum and the maximum from a matrix from each column.
My function

```
public static void findMinMax(double[][] matrix) {
        ArrayList<Double> column = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> minmax = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> minMaxValues = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
            for (int j=0;j<matrix[1].length;j++) {
                column.clear();
                minmax.clear();
                for (int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
                    column.add(matrix[i][j]);
                }
                double max = Collections.max(column);
                double min = Collections.min(column);
                minmax.add(min);
                minmax.add(max);
                try {
                    System.out.println("adding to final minmax " + j);
                    minMaxValues.add(minmax);
                    System.out.println(minMaxValues);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(minMaxValues);
    }
```

The problem is that at the last iteration it adds to `minMaxValues` only the last `minmax` ArrayList.
Here is an example of the output

```
adding to final minmax 0
[[-3.5, 4.5]]
adding to final minmax 1
[[-3.5, 4.5], [-3.5, 4.5]]
adding to final minmax 2
[[-3.5, 4.5], [-3.5, 4.5], [-3.5, 4.5]]
adding to final minmax 3
[[-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 4
[[-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 5
[[-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 6
[[-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2], [-3.5, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 7
[[-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 8
[[-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 9
[[-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2], [-3.9, 4.2]]
adding to final minmax 10
[[-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5], [-3.9, 4.5]]
```

As you can see it works fine until minmax 10 where I don't understand what happens. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what does `matrix[1].length` evaluate to? 11?

Comment: Yes, matrix has 10 rows and 11 columns

Comment: What is going wrong? your problem is not clear

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't understand what you mean...Why it works fine until the last column and the adds only the last pair of minmax?

Comment: See my answer. You're just storing 11 references to the same `minmax` list. The contents of the list itself are overwritten in every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialize `ArrayList<Double> minmax` for every iteration. Otherwise your result list will just contain 11 references to the **same list**, containing the last values that you put in.

You need to move

```
ArrayList<Double> minmax = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

inside your loop.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I'm still trying to understand why :)

Comment: Try to wrap your head around the fact that your `minMaxValues` just contains 11 references to the same `minmax` list. That list is in the state that you leave after the last iteration, hence containing the values of the last iteration.